# How to display an object which doesn't belong to my model?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, listbox

I'm doing a web project in ASP MVC 4.
I have a strongly typed(model :Product) view (ProductIndex.cshtml) and I want to display a list of all the merchants in this view.

What is the best approach ?
-Create a new property in my Product class (Icollection) ?
I don't really like this approach because a Product is not supposed to have a List of Merchants...
-Create a partial View typed (IEnumerable) and call it from my ProductIndex View  with a ViewData object as parameter? 
I'm not sure I'll be able to display the model(IEnumerable) in a Listbox with this approach ...I guess I can only populate a listbox with a property and not with a model...
Tell me pls!

Thank you

```cs
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int MerchandID { get; set; }


    }

 public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int MerchandID { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<Merchant> Lesmarchands { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product Product {get;set;}
    public List<Merchant> Merchants {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I have an error with this code ecause Entity need to have an ID property in the view model class so I will copy all the properties of my Product object in this class instead of having a Product property.

Comment: don't do that. use Product.ID and in client side, the name of the html element should be <element name = "Product.ID" />

Comment: I'm not able to create a new view based on this Viewmodel.I get an error:ProductviewModel:EntityType'ProductViewModel' has no key defined.Define the key for this entitytype.ProductViewModels:EntityType:entitySet 'ProductviewModels' is based on type 'ProductviewModel'that has no key defined. i don't understand how and why this entity 'ProductviewmodelS' is created ?

Comment: Have you got a PK in your Product? Can you show your Product model?

Comment: Yes and a FK MerchantID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it as bad to have a list of merchants associated with your product view model.
Especially if both are needed to satisfy the needs of your view. I tend to create view models on top of my models as an abstraction on top of the actual domain model.

Of course a slightly different approach is to load the merchants through Ajax and disconnect them from the product in the model.

Comment: No I would said it's bad idea to have a list of merchants in the product model...But I didn't think to create a VIEW model product...I used the Product model as a View Model...That was not the best idea I guess